# echo does not print command output as expected

Tags: bash

This following command prints nothing on my machine

```sh
echo `python3.8 -c 'print ("*"*10)'`
```

whereas

```sh
python3.8 -c 'print ("*"*10)'
```

does. Why?

Comment: What OS/shell? I get `**********` in zsh (macOS default) and a list of the things in my current directory in bash, for example.

Comment: Unless you are trying to embed the output of Python in a larger string, capturing the output only to write it to standard output again with `echo` isn't necessary.

Comment: Similar: [When should I wrap quotes around a shell variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10067266/when-to-wrap-quotes-around-a-variable); relevant: [Security implications of forgetting to quote a variable in bash/POSIX shells](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/171346/security-implications-of-forgetting-to-quote-a-variable-in-bash-posix-shells)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first example does command substitution for the argument to `echo` and is equivalent to the command `echo **********`. This happens to output a list of directory contents, since `**********` seems to be equivalent to `*`<sup>1</sup> and is expanded by the shell.

If you want to prevent the shell to expand `**********`, you need to quote it:

```sh
echo "`python3.8 -c 'print ("*"*10)'`"
```

which is equivalent to `echo "**********"`.

---

<sup>1</sup><sub>don't quote me on that (pun intended)</sub>

Comment: But of course, that's a [useless use of `echo`](https://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html#echo)

Comment: Interestingly, in an empty directory, `echo *` does output `*`.

Comment: That depends on your glob settings. Bourne shell or Bash out of the box yes; Bash with `nullglob` no.

Answer (score 1):

`expr` means to evaluate the contents between ' as a command and replace it with the result.

`print(*)` is equal to ` * ` which is evaluated as all the files in the current directory

The output really depends on the machine used

Comment: expr? that does not appear in the question.

Comment: expr as in expression, _any expression_

Comment: Oh, I see you mean any expression between backticks. That could be more clearly explained, particularly as you then show a single quote.